# Android bluetooth push files

Tags: android, bluetooth

i want to send files via Bluetooth to a another device. 
I want to send files to a device programmatically. Has anyone a idea how 
i can send files via Bluetooth OPP?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following,

- Step 1 add bluetooth permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  ```
- Step 2 use following code to send a file.

  ```
  BluetoothDevice device; String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/data.txt";  
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
  values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString()); 
  values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress()); 
  values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND); 
  Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis(); values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts); 
  Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
  ```
- Step 3 you can download [BluetoothShare.java](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/ag-gb-dsds-7227/repository/revisions/18065ea37751cc6fc3a07430b22f469df8d29339/changes/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothShare.java) from the link.

done.