# Bluez implementation in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Can anyone please provide us any source code for bluez implementation in android. Actually we are trying to make an application with GATT profile. This android application should connect with other device by Bluetooth connection. Please suggest me what should be the best way to send data to a non android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at Bluetooth chat example by Google, you also can use the same method to connect to a non android device.
Specifically you will need this api

> device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID);

EDIT: 
You can also try using reflection to access another method like this

```
Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Comment: I have gone through the Bluetooth chat . But when I tried to connect with non android device  but whenever the socket tries to connect(mmSocket.connect(); ) it is throwing IO-exception. But in case of two android devices it is working fine. Please suggest me..

Comment: then catch the exception and start debugging, i can confirm that it works for non android devices, as i have used the same api to connect to a separate bluetooth module

Comment: I am getting Service discovery failed IO exception. do u faces this kind of exception.

Comment: You are probably using the wrong UUID
Both the host and slave should be on the same UUID, 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB is a common UUID for a serial connection.

Comment: connection is done but what is the way to send data to non android device .. I am doing output stream but its not working.. Please tell me what is the way to send any data to non android device.

Comment: Output stream is the correct way, something like this..
OutStream.write(a_bytesOfData)

Comment: yeah that what i m doing but nothing is happening on the non android device .How will I understand it is working as I cant debug on non android device.

Comment: What device exactly are you trying to connect to ?

Comment: its lg simbean OS. I mean if u can post me the code for sending data to another non android device it will be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188639/send-file-to-other-bluetooth-device-from-android?lq=1

Comment: if you need to send something else you need a app running on the other os

Comment: I tried to send a jpg file. But nothing received in the non andorid phone... :(